# Compose BasicTextField focus issues

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

encountered couple of issues and got a couple of questions regarding focus and BasicTextField when making some equivalent of searchView:

1. Is there a better way to get focus when entering screen than this below? (i have an issue with SideEffect launching keyboard when splash screen is being shown, and not showing up on the proper one)
2. After gaining focus i cannot get the keyboard to showup (i assume its related to 1st one but not sure), tried doing keyboardController.showkeyboard() in SideEffect
3. i have a requirement where search icon needs to have a certain alpha value depending on focusState, if i uncomment the 3 commented lines, the If inside alpha modifier stops working

https://gist.github.com/piotrsedlak/2c5011210d41fcf4979cdd24ec286d4c

Comment: I believe this has been fixed in the latest alpha-11. You should try it out

Comment: I am on alpha-11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was with emulator not the code itself.

After running it on device, it worked fine